# Displaying a user-customized part on a web site

Tags: silverlight, flash, rendering

I'm building a web site (asp.net) for a company that manufactures small customizable anodized aluminum products. Products are a variety of shapes. but mostly flat, domed or ring-shaped. Products can be colored in one of about 15 colors.

The user can specify one or more lines of text and a font, a simple line drawing (e.g., a heart or four-leafed clover), or both. Text is limited to about 5-15 characters per line. The text or drawing is milled into the part and can be colored in a contrasting color.

What I want to do is display the customized product to the user, so that after selecting product, colors, text,, font and artwork the site will display an image of how the finished product will look. Ideally they would be able to rotate the image but that's not critical.

I have digital descriptions (CAD and CNC milling instructions) of all the parts, fonts, and artwork and can translate them into whatever format is needed.

Can this be done with Flash, SilverLight, or some similar technology? Ideas, references, suggestions, and tutorials welcome! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in Flash, but it requires a lot of work:

To get a realistic version of the product displayed, you have to produce pictures, videos and whatever other depictions of all possible shapes and colors of your product, then you simply have to switch between those depending on the user's choice.

Adding the writing is a bit trickier when the surface isn't flat, but you can model a dome or ring-shaped surface with 3D polygons and add the text as an image texture.

It is best to have a set of standard views, maybe 4 or 5 angles, so that you only have to figure each position out once for each similar shape, and afterwards you can just copy the positioning etc.